# Insert a new column from an existing column in python using dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a a new column based on the elements present in another column of a dataframe.
For instance:

```
|Sales                                      |
|------------------------------------------ |
|{id: 1, name: pen, sold: 250, profit:10}   |
|{id: 3, name: eraser, sold: 47, profit:0.8}|
|{id: 7, name: book, sold: 780, profit:85}  |
```

to look like

```
Sales                                       | name | sold |
--------------------------------------------|------|------|
{id: 1, name: pen, sold: 250, profit:10}    |pen   | 250  |
{id: 3, name: eraser, sold: 47, profit:0.8} |eraser| 47   |
{id: 7, name: book, sold: 780, profit:85}   |book  | 780  |
```

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Sales'])`?

Comment: it's of type dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `str` accessor:

```
df['name']=df['Sales'].str['name']
df['sold']=df['Sales'].str['sold']
```

output:

| Sales | name | sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {id: 1, name: pen, sold: 250, profit:10} | pen | 250 |
| {id: 3, name: eraser, sold: 47, profit:0.8} | eraser | 47 |
| {id: 7, name: book, sold: 780, profit:85} | book | 780 |

Comment: Thanks for `str` accessor. This doesn't show a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
df['name'] = df['Sales'].apply(lambda x: x.get('name')
df['sold'] = df['Sales'].apply(lambda x: x.get('sold'))
```